# How to convert this lambda command to a function in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

How could I convert the following line of code using a lambda command into a function by itself?

I am struggling to get the hang of lambda, and wanted to apply it to an example I found.  I am confused about how to convert the `x` and `y` when I put it in it's own function, like `def sortedList(myList)`

The line with the lambda is as follows:

```
myList = [[1,2],[19,20],[2,3]]    
listNums = sorted(myList, 
                      sortList = lambda x,y: x[0] + y[0] if x[0] == y[0] else y[1] - x[1])
```

Comment: The equivalent code without a lambda would be `raise TypeError("'sortList' is an invalid keyword argument for this function")`

Answer (score 1):

```
listNums = sorted(myList, 
                  sortList = lambda x,y: x[0] + y[0] if x[0] == y[0] else y[1] - x[1])
```

is equivalent to

```
def funcname(x,y):
    return x[0] + y[0] if x[0] == y[0] else y[1] - x[1]

listNums = sorted(myList, sortList=funcname)
```

However, that is not the correct syntax for `sorted` - it should be

```
listNums = sorted(mylist, cmp=funcname)
```

To address your comment, sorted uses the `cmp` function to sort the elements of your list.  In your question, your list is 
`[[1,2],[19,20],[2,3]]`.  The basic question is, which comes first `[1,2]` or `[19,20]`?  Because that question could be answered nearly infinite different ways, it lets you provide the answer with a cmp function.  In that case, to decide which of those pairs comes first, sorted will run `cmp(x=[1,2], y=[19,20])`.  If the value is > 0, it assumes x is higher, if it is < 0 it considers y as higher, and if the return value is 0 it figures they are the same value.

The example you chose seems a weird way to do comparisons... if the first values are equal, return the sum of the first values?  If they are both positive, then x will always be higher, if they are both negative, y will always be higher.  If they aren't equal, sort solely based on the second value.

Comment: More nuance required: you can't just replace the one with the other. For one thing, a lambda can only contain a single expression, which is returned with a `return` statement

Comment: Hi Paul.  Thanks for the response.  I understand what you wrote in your answer.  But I am stumped on how to convert this example into a function.  For example, my list has three pairs.  But the sortList function is only addressing `x[0]` and `y[0]`.